# MYSQL if table exit run something otherwise run another thing

Tags: mysql, sql-server, converters

I have problem to convert the following code from MSSQL to MySQL.

```
IF Object_ID('myTable') is not null
begin
    DROP INDEX uq_myTable ON dbo.myTable
    drop table myTable
end
go
create table myTable(
  id int primary Key identity(1,1),
  post int
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_myTable
  ON dbo.myTable(pos);
```

So basically the above code could make a table name "myTable" and an unique index as uq_myTable.  It also delete the index and the corresponded table before it re-create it.

I am looking to convert these codes to MySQL. The problem is that I could not find IF statement that based on the result of the if statement I tell to MYSQL what it should does ( if table exists is should delete the index and table and  re-create the table and index, and if the table does not exists simply it creates the table and the index)

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server, you have to pick one that you are using.

Comment: This code is MS SQL and I want to translate it to MYSQL to work. For the tags I selected SQL SERVER as there were not any MSSQL for taging

Comment: You're right. Sorry for my mistake :)

Comment: To be more specific than the linked question: the index gets removed with the table, so you do not need to have a separate statement for this. If you need to do other things based on the test: [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) is only supported in stored programs, so you would need to generate a (dummy) procedure for it. But for just dropping the table (and the index), `drop table if exists` suffices.

Comment: Solarflare, could you please explain more regarding to the index solution? I am looking for a simple trick like drop table if exists for removing the index but I could not figure it out how

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand your problem. You do not need to drop the index. If you drop the table, the index is gone too, so all you need is a `drop table if exists myTable; create table ...`.  If you are trying to solve a different problem, you should specify that.

Comment: Thanks Solarflare but are you sure if you drop a table the index also will drop? This is not the case in MSSQL but maybe in MYSQL if you drop a table it drop the index too

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I actually only added the comment to ensure you that I considered that, as it was not explicitly mentioned in the other question (because, well, it is not relevant for MySQL, so the author of that question had no reason to mention indexes on their table). Not sure if I complicated things for you that way.